# How do I get the Aegean theme to work with the JasperCompileManager?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to use the JasperReports library in a plain Java application. It won't compile because it can't find the aegean chart theme. Can someone point me to a simple example of how to get a .jrxml file to compile and pass this theme to the JasperCompileManager?

```
package com.asset.jasper.mvc.reports;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.chartthemes.simple.AegeanSettingsFactory;
import net.sf.jasperreports.chartthemes.simple.XmlChartTheme;
import net.sf.jasperreports.chartthemes.spring.AegeanChartTheme;

public class AssetReport {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog (AssetReport.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, IOException {
        AegeanChartTheme aegeanChartTheme = new AegeanChartTheme();

        XmlChartTheme.saveSettings(
                AegeanSettingsFactory.createChartThemeSettings(),
                new File("src/net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/simple/aegean.jrctx")
                );

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(
                "/resources/ARKREPORT.jrxml");

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Connection myconnection = getConnection();
        String jdbcString = "select * from asset";
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = myconnection.prepareStatement(jdbcString.toString());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JRDataSource dataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);

        File outDir = new File("/Users/denisputnam/tmp");
        outDir.mkdirs();

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "/tmp/StyledTextReport.pdf");
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, "/tmp/StyledTextReport.html");
    }

    static public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/assetcore", "assetcore", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it be that just a forward slash is missing in your `File("/src/net/sf/jasperreports......`?

Comment: No, I am doing a "run as" in the IDE.  That's okay, we have decided not to use jasper reports.  It has too many problems and the learning curve is too high.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that. What does a "run as" change when the path is wrong? Also, just out of curiosity: which solution will you take now, as I suspect everything has a high learning curve?